# Безаффиксный или бессуффиксный.

Tags: словообразование

Есть ли разница между бессуффиксным и безаффиксным способом образования слов?

Answer (score 7):

Да, в лингвистике это синонимы. Безаффиксный (бессуффиксный, способ нулевой суффиксации)-образование новых слов, а именно имен существительных, от производящей основы глагола или имени прилагательного без добавления аффиксов. Взрыв, накал, поиск, разбег, синь, зелень, гниль,  удаль и т.п.

Answer (score 3):

вообще-то понятие Аффикс применимо не только к суффиксу. Оно обозначает и префикс - приставка, и постфикс - ся,/сь, и интерфикс - соединительные гласные о-е. Поэтому о полной синонимии говорить нельзя.

Comment: Согласна. Но вопрос о способах образования. В терминологии способов образования эти слова - синонимы. И если вы видите разницу в этих способах, то объясните, пожалуйста, на примерах: вот это слово - бессуфиксным способом образовано, а вот это-  безаффиксным. Буду благодарна.

Comment: @larf, например, все краткие прилагательные образованы безаффиксным способом, но не безсуффиксным.

Comment: Марк Из, Вы смешиваете формо- и словообразование. Краткая и полная формы слова - это формы одного и того же слова, отличаются только окончанием. ЛЗ слова не меняется, меняется его грамматическое значение.  А в вопросе речь идет о способах образования слов.

Comment: @Ларf, не могу согласиться с тем, что лексическое значение (ЛЗ?) не изменяется. Краткое прилагательное в отличии от полного дополнительно выражает субъективность данного определения. Сравните: *"Как-то на картине всё синевато - Как-то на картине всё синеватое"* В первом случае, говориться о том, что общее впечатление о картине - много синего цвета, во втором - что во всех элементах картины есть синий цвет. Также краткое прилагательное имеет свойство обобщения: *Красивы девушки, живущие в России - Красивые девушки, живущие в России.*

Так что, краткие прилагательные - это, именно, словоформа.

Comment: Краткое прилагательное - это форма полного. Соглашусь, что все краткие прилагательные обозначают признак не такой, как полные. иногда мы видим оттенки в значении, и если хотим подчеркнуть временность проявления признака - употребим краткое прилагательное. Папа злой (вообще)- папа зол (сейчас). Но это не разные значения конкретного прилагательного. И Вы верно говорите, что это словоформа, т.е. одно и то же слово. А значит о способе словообразования говорить не приходится.

Comment: Прилагательное синевато (синеватый) - образовано от прилагательного синий суффиксальным способом. Безаффиксный способ здесь ни при чем.

Comment: Марк Из, в Вашем примере слово СИНЕВАТО вообще похоже на категорию состояния, а не на краткую форму. А если рассуждать по-ВАШЕМУ, ТО И СЛОВО МАМА И МАМЫ (ВО МН.Ч.)ТОЖЕ ОЗНАЧАЮТ НЕ ОДНО И ТО ЖЕ. Но, тем не менее, Вы же не станете спорить, что это формы слов, а не разные слова. Ларf, спасибо за уточнение. Действительно, если речь о способах образования, то да - это синонимы.

Answer (score -2):

Да, аффикс - это любая морфема (кроме корня?)